# Simple Popup Close

Tags: jquery, popup

How do I terminate this popup with a close button? Or some sort of div? I tried this way:

```
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
    jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
    jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
    jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
    jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
    jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
    jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
    jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
    jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
  }
} );

jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {

    if (location.region_name === 'Utah') {

      $('#message').parent().show(); 

    }
    else{
      $(".close").click(function(){
      $("#message").hide();
      });
    }
  }
} );
```

And it isn't working. By using the .hide(); I was assuming that it would automatically hide the div?

Here is the HTML that has been used to display this popup. The popup is using geolocation, to detect location and popup, I need it to then close via click.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>This is a popup</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    #message
    {
        width:516px;
        height:508px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-image: url(test.jpg);
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        margin-left:-250px;
        margin-top:-250px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="message">
    <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a>
  </div>  
</div>

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `.show()`ing the parent `div`

```
$('#message').parent().show();
```

and then hiding the direct `div`

```
$('#message').hide();
```

It should still be hiding the `$('#message')` div but clearly it's not the desired outcome.

### Example

```js
$('.open').on('click', function(){
  $('.msg').show();
})


$('.msg .close').on('click', function(){
  $('.msg').hide();
})

$.ajax( "http://example.com/some/fake/page" )
  .done(function() {
    
  })
  .fail(function() {
    
    // the ajax request fails, but this could be placed in the `.done()` handler above.
    $('.msg').show();
  
  })
```

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(255,230,230);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.msg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(230,255,230);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.msg .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <span class="open pointer">open</span>
  <div class="msg" style="display:none">
    <span class="close pointer">close</span>
    <h2>Message</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So something like: $("#message").parent().hide(); ? However, this will then just reloop and show the message again no? How do I hide it until revisit?

Comment: Updated my answer with a snippet, there's no reason hiding the parent should re run the ajax request from the code you've provided.

Comment: Yeah do I understand you opened on click, and closed with click. But my popup opens via the geolocation function, how do I then close via click? Updated with HTML

Comment: I see, I don't understand why you have a parent div at all? you could simply remove it and apply the `display:none` style to the `#message` div. You can also take the `$('.close')` function out of the ajax request as I have. Updated my answer to be even more similar.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that just doesn't help solve the problem. I need the popup to open on function(location), not on click. But then close on click. You are opening on click, then closing on click. Completely different unfortunately.

Comment: @JeffRodger I am now using an ajax request in the demo above, the request fails because the url does not exist. But it shows the functionality you're looking for - does that help?